# How to specify the IDE Netbeans, that the PHP variable has a specific type?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

I have file with some PHP code, like this:

```
    <?php
        foreach ($ideas as $key => $idea) {
            $idea->getIdeaId();
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Variable $ideas is an array of objects with type KIdea. How can I tell to Netbeans, what `$idea` in `foreach` will have type `KIdea`?

It's need for the code completition.

I have try something like

```
        <?php
        /**
         *  @param KIdea $ideas Description
         */
        foreach ($ideas as $key => $idea) {
```

and something like

```
        <?php
        foreach ($ideas as $key => $idea) {
            /**
             *  @var KIdea Description
             */
            $idea;
            $idea->getIdeaId();
```

but it's not helpful for the code completion.

Comment: Does [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_a_variable_type_in) help you ?

Comment: @JulienFastré, JulienFastré, yes, your comment is more helpful, then others :) .

Comment: I have written a full answer for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With netbeans, you may document your variable with the following syntax :

```
/* @var $variable MyClass */
$variable = getSomething();

// netbeans will assume that your variable is the MyClass type and will provide code completion.
```

To auto-complete this string, you may use the following shortcut: type  `vdoc` and press `Tab` key.

[Source for this answer on the Oracles's netbeans php blog.](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/defining_a_variable_type_in)

Answer (score 0):

You have to isolate the code of `foreach` iteration in a separate function where you can use phpDoc notation as well as type hinting

Comment: That's the more elegant option, I agree.  Any time I have trouble using an existing and well-known phpdoc tag, I take it as a "code smell" and reconsider how I've implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs have implemented a way to document a local variable like that, though to my knowledge the format is not exactly standardized across IDEs, nor in phpDoc syntax (though it's being proposed in PHP-FIG's PSR5 draft).

Use the `@var` tag to indicate a datatype for the local variable you want to document.  The syntax variability in the various IDE implementations is usually the ordering of those values, e.g. is it `@var \KIdea $idea` or is it `@var $idea \KIdea`.  Since this is not a docblock tied to an OOP code element, it needs the local variable's name in order to tie its info to the right variable.